# value is not assigned to variable state in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im new to react native. when I receive data from server and set the data to variable in alert nothing to show for me can help me to fix this? tank you

```
   const [result, setResult] = useState('')

    Server(mydata).then(data => {
    //data value is ok 
    //when set data value to setResult
    //dose not show anything in alert
    setResult(data.data)        
    alert(setResult)
   })
```

Comment: setResult is a function not a value

Answer (score 0):

Because setResult() is an async operation, you should be using useEffect to wait for the result and make the alert. Something like this:

```
const [result, setResult] = useState('')

Server(mydata).then(data => {
    //data value is ok 
    //when set data value to setResult
    //dose not show anything in alert
    setResult(data.data)
})

useEffect(() => {
    alert(result)
}, [result])
```